# How to set list of chars and list of integers into one list?

Tags: java, list

How to set list of chars and list of integers into one list? I have two lists which I took from hash map and now I have to format it into pretty view. After formatting I have two lists one of integers and other one of characters. Is it possible to put this values into one array list

```
 private List<Character> convertToList(){
    Set<Character> mapKeyToList = output().keySet();
    List<Character> keys = new ArrayList<>(mapKeyToList);
    return keys;
}
private List<Integer> convertInts(){
    Collection<Integer> values = output().values();
    List<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<>(values);
    return quantity;
}
```

**Example of output :**

```
"char" - int
"char" - int
"char" - int
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `entrySet` from your map and get in new ArrayList

```
List<Entry<Character, Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>(output().entrySet());
```

You can get key and value using `.getKey()` and `.getValue()`

```
for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : res) {
  Character c = entry.getKey();
  Integer i = entry.getValue();
  // formatting 
}
```

Here you can directly use `resultMap.entrySet()` instead of `res` in loop also.

Comment: will be possible to format strings and integers separately ?

Comment: Yes you can format then separately, getting from `Entry`. Yes you don't need 2 list

Comment: @marzocchi every `Entry` in the `List` has a `getKey()` and a `getValue()` method and you've declared the type of the key and of the value

Comment: At this point, you can just loop through output.entrySet directly, rather than creating a separate list containing the same data and then looping through that.

Comment: @RiaanNel Yes, you are right. I am doing this because OP wants to collect in a ArrayList as answer _Is it possible to put this values into one array list_

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both lists are the same size (which they should be, if they are created from the same map), you can just use a for loop to pull elements from each list and populate the new list.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        
for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
    newList.add(String.format("%s - %d", chars.get(i), ints.get(i)));
}
```

Of course, you could also loop over the map and do this with the Streams API if you are using Java 8 or later.

```
    List<String> result = values.entrySet().stream()
            .map(x -> String.format("%s - %d", x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```